# Managing Test Data for UI testing

Tags: java, test-design, testng, test-data, data-driven

I am working on a Java/TestNG UI automation framework and having some difficulties with test data management.

I use TestNG's DataProvider to pass data to the test method.
I need to pass about 30 variables to test an end to end scenario and I have about 150 scenarios to test.

I saved each variable in a cell in an excel sheet and treat each row as a scenario. (150 rows, 30 cells in each row)

So I read the items in one row, create my Java object using those variables and pass that object to my test method to test one scenario.

Managing this data is a little difficult. Is there a preferred approach for this kind of problem?

Comment: What exactly is difficult? I want to know to answer your question, because simply adding values to an Excel doesn't seem that overwhelming.

Answer (score 1):

When the growth of your data leads to a situation where managing the data is becoming burdensome, one option that I would consider would be moving to a formal database for storage of that information.
You could have various tables to store the data.
You will need a UI to manage the data of course.  With mySQL that could simply be SQLworkbench (free).  Another option is to create a simple UI for that data, e.g. build a simple app using Ruby-on-Rails or Sinatra.

Answer (score 1):

One TestNG approach is to use Parameterized Tests

See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_parameterized_test.htm

> Another interesting feature available in TestNG is parametric testing.
>   In most cases, you'll come across a scenario where the business logic
>   requires a hugely varying number of tests. Parameterized tests allow
>   developers to run the same test over and over again using different
>   values.

Answer (score 0):

If you find that most data tends to be key-value pairs, e.g. for this element use this value, for that element use that value, etc. you may want to store the data as key-value pairs in a file.  You can then access that file and if desired read the key-value pairs into dynamically created methods for a data provider object.  You can also use systems such as redis that are based on key-value pairs as this may address sharing the data without physically passing around a file (or access to it).

Answer (score 0):

Just like the [PageObject pattern](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) where you store locators and actions in a class I like to use a class as a central test-data store.

Just like [data-structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) classes you can create test-data classes. It should have some public variables or methods that return single data entries or arrays/lists you can use in [parameterized tests](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_parameterized_test.htm).

I would alway try to prevent to use Excel. As it is hard(er) to version with the code, because it is a binary file format. Also developers need to use an extra tool to update the tests for their code. Going back and forth between the test-data and the code, horrible, better if you can stay in your IDE.

Put the test-data next to your code, unless you have non technical people who need to update the test-data. In that case I would use something like [Fitnesse](http://www.fitnesse.org/) where you map (unit-)tests with data in a Wiki.

Ask yourself these questions:

- Can I version my data?
- Do I need extra tools?
- Do I have on technical people who need to update test-data?

Try to keep it as simple as possible. Excel just adds complexity you do not need probably. Apply the [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) principle.

Answer (score -1):

Excel is one of the ways to store your input data.

1. You can also use .properties file as in a key-value pair for the same purpose.
2. Or you create a BaseClass (or TestData Class) which you can extend(inherit) into your Test class.